# django - how to get model objects from another process instead of database

Tags: python, django, web-applications, django-models

I have a TCP server, a Python app, that gets the information from the connected devices. This information I am trying to show using Django web app. So, basically my model objects reside within the TCP server process.
I can modify the TCP server to put the information into SQLite database and have my Django web app take it from there. But, it is not the most natural way of sharing information in this case because this information is not persistent i.e. not suitable for database. When my TCP server exists, it has to clear this information.

How do I model this scenario using Django?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be able to serialise your model and pass the serialised data.

Answer (score 0):

i think better to use `memcached (http://memcached.org/) in mem cached server and each server see this server

also you can serialize your data and send it like udp and other method

Comment: thanks for your input. I looked into memcached. It's more about caching the response of some server requests. Also, I did not want to run a separate server. In the end, I went for multiprocessing module: http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html